# Velodyne package for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there anyone working on velodyne package release for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?
If not i'd like to do it.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236814/velodyne-package-for-ubuntu-16.04-lts?/) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-06-15**:
Have you tried building it from source on Kinetic?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-06-16**:
I built it yesterday on Xenial and Kinetic with no problems, and it passed all the unit tests. So, you can run it from source until a binary release is available.

**Comment by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on 2016-06-17**:
Thanks Jack, I'll build it from source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please don't.

There are new Indigo and Jade releases in the pipeline. Kinetic will come after that.

Thanks for inquiring. I opened issue [#93](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/93) to track resolution of your problem.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These instructions worked for me:

https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/ros_binaries

---

Originally posted by [markstrefford](https://answers.ros.org/users/30039/markstrefford/) with karma: 11 on 2017-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1